# Why does blocking the thread cause the floating window to fail to open?

Tags: android, accessibility, kotlin-coroutines, android-windowmanager

```kotlin
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
  override fun onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected()
    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    showOverlay()
  }

  private fun showOverlay() {   
    // omitted about composeView code
    
    windowManager.addView(composeView, params)

    runBlocking(newSingleThreadContext("MyOwnThread")) {
      while (true) {
        delay(1000 * 10)
        windows.forEach { println(it) }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Why does blocking the thread with `runBlocking` after `windowManager.addView` cause the floating window not working?

I don't see any connection between the two?

Comment: This is exactly why we can't block the UI thread. UI framework can't do almost anything while we block its critical resource which is the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You're preventing `onServiceConnected()` from ever returning, so the OS cannot even finish setting it up and continuing its lifecycle.

You need to run your coroutine in a scope that is cancelled when the service is destroyed, or you will leak everything forever. Something like this:

```
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
  private val lifecycleScope = MainScope() + CoroutineName("MyAccessibilityService lifecycleScope")

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    lifecycleScope.cancel()
  }

  override fun onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected()
    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    showOverlay()
  }

  private fun showOverlay() {   
    // omitted about composeView code
    
    windowManager.addView(composeView, params)

    lifecycleScope.launch {
      while (true) {
        delay(1000 * 10)
        windows.forEach { println(it) }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `windowManager.addView` executed or not executed in my code example?

Comment: It is executed, but the real change happens after you free the thread, so it could be used to apply UI changes.

Comment: Changes made to UI-related classes may be executed immediately, but their effects only occur (become visible) on the next frame of execution on the main thread.

Comment: Why does the system not report an ANR error even if the UI thread is blocked?

Comment: I don’t know how long it takes before it appears. Might vary by android version from 5-15 seconds? Is this even on the main thread? I’ve never used AccessibilityService. Or it could have to do with which process it’s running in in your app.

Comment: I can confirm that it has been stuck for more than a few minutes without ANR errors. I don't know if it's on the main thread, which thread the accessibility service is on should be system controlled.